# Bootstrap modal dialog pushed below all other html

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

The following image shows how the modal html (which is a top-level node in the body) is being pushed to the bottom of all the other html, rather than sitting on top as it should. I haven't modified any CSS (straight Bootstrap). Any ideas/experience that might explain this behavior?

[image: Modal pushed down.]

Comment: Did you forget a `clearfix` class on the container element of the red and blue boxes? I assume you are floating them.

Comment: I used container-fluid -> row -> col-lg-4, col-lg-8 for a dynamic layout. The container-fluid is at the same level as the modal.

Comment: It would help if we could see your HTML markup.

Comment: Please post your HTML and a JS Fiddle or JS Bin.

Comment: Will do, as soon as I can.